# Webpack global/process.env variables scope?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I've got a Webpack server that takes in options, compiles code and returns it as a string (not just a local or pipeline build tool but an actual production service). I need static options/feature flags to decide what code to keep and what feature to use.

As far as I know, I've got 2 options: [`DefinePlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) and [`EnvironmentPlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/environment-plugin/).

**But** Webpack I/O is asynchronous and so is my request handling logic.

Is there a chance that if process is asynchronous, 1. request sets "global options", starts compiling, 2. request comes in and sets its "global options" and 1. request compilation continues and **uses 2. request options**?

Or are defined global/process.env variables only scoped to that specific compilation? Both plugins?

```js
// inside Webpack config

// option 1
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  OPTION1: JSON.stringify(option1),
  OPTION2: JSON.stringify(option2),
});

// option 2
process.env.OPTION1 = option1;
process.env.OPTION2 = option2;
new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin(['OPTION1', 'OPTION2']);


// Webpack programmatic API
const compiler = webpack(config);
compiler.run(...);


// in code
// if OPTION1 is falsey, this block
// isn't added to final bundle
if (OPTION1) {
  // dynamic import/require fancy feature X
}
```

Comment: `process.env` is process-wide, so depending on how EnvironmentPlugin is implemented, it either reads environment variables only once (at startup) or whenever it's invoked (which causes the problem you're worried about). So EnvironmentPlugin is not a good choice here. However, with DefinePlugin the entire configuration appears to be contained within the plugin, so it should be safe. Just make sure to create a new compiler object for every request.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks, this seems about right. Could you make an answer I can accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`process.env` is process-wide, so depending on how `EnvironmentPlugin` is implemented, it either reads environment variables only once (at startup) or whenever it's invoked (which causes the problem you're worried about). So `EnvironmentPlugin` is not a good choice here.

However, with `DefinePlugin` the entire configuration appears to be contained within the plugin, so it should be safe. Just make sure to create a new compiler object for every request.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question right when you run webpack compilation you want to do it differently based on some condition. Instead of using environmental variables you could actually just pass your condition directly to webpack config.

First make webpack config a function accepting arguments:

```
module.exports = ({param1, param2, param3}) => {
  return {
    mode: 'production',
    context: path.resolve(__dirname),
    entry: `${param1}.js`,
    output: {path: param2, filename: `${param3}.js`},
    module: {
        rules: [
        ]
    },
    plugins: [

    ]
  };
};
```

And second when you call compiler.run just pass those arguments to webpack config:

```
let webpackConfig = require('./webpack-config-file.js')({
  param1: "argument-for-webpack-config",
  param2: "argument-for-webpack-config",
  param3: "argument-for-webpack-config"
});

const compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);
  compiler.run((err, stats) => {
    if (err || stats.hasErrors()) {
      // show errors
    }
      // do something
 });
```

Comment: I need these params in actual code that is compiled and I don't want different compilations to intervene with each other (i.e change each others settings).

Comment: each time you run compiler.run it runs a new instance of webpack, so different instances will not have common params